# Label groups in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
id   name
0     Bob
1   Alice
2     Bob
3   
4     Bob
5    Mary
6   Alice
```

I need to assign a `group_id` to each distinct name:

```
id   name   group_id
0     Bob          0  -- Bob's group
1   Alice          1  -- Alice's group
2     Bob          0  -- Bob's group
3                     -- no group (NULL)
4     Bob          0  -- Bob's group
5    Mary          2  -- Mary's group
6   Alice          1  -- Alice's group
```

Can this be done in one line in MySQL?

I know I could find the unique names with an autoincrement column, then JOIN back with the original table based on the name -- but I was wondering if there exists a simpler/faster solution...

Comment: With 200k records you'll probably be better off joining a view of the table that assigns unique groups to everyone instead of doing 200k inline select statements. Any particular reason you are opposed to joins here?

Comment: No, no, I'm not opposed to joins, I was just wondering if there exists a smarter/faster/neater way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use case. Just add a new computed column based on an expression that outputs the appropriate value for each string value of the `name` column

```
Select id, name, 
   case name
      when 'Bob' then 0 
      when 'Alice' then 1 
      when 'Mary' then 2 
      -- etc.
      end GroupId
From table
```

If you don't know the names in advance, or if there are too many, try this:

```
Select id, name,
  (select count(distinct name) 
   from table 
   where name < t.Name) groupId
From table t
```

Unless you add an index on the name column, this will be very slow on a large table.

To output a null instead of a 0 for rows with name = null, use this:

```
Select id, name,
  case when name is null then null 
    else (select count(distinct name) 
          from table 
          where name < t.Name) end groupId
From table t
```

Comment: I don't know the strings in advance. Even if I knew them -- there are thousands of them.

Comment: Then, if you don't know names in advance, you cannot easily control the group ids. Use subquery with a count (distinct) in it to generate the numeric group id values.

Comment: I am trying to port this from Pyhton/pandas, where I have a function `ngroup()` which returns the number assigned to each group in a `group_by()` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html). So i don't need to count how many elements each group has, but to assign a numeric code to each group. I don't know SQL very well, bt it seems to me that `count (distinct name)` doesn't help here.

Comment: This does not count the number of elements IN the group, it calculates the ranking of the group. It's the sequential position of that group name in an ordered list of the distinct group names, (1, 2, 3, ... etc.). It counts the number of distinct group names which would sort, alphabetically, BEFORE this group name.  Did you try this query?

Comment: Aha, I get it. Then it seems to be what I need. No, I didn't test the query, I'm just trying to prove to someone that the Python/pandas thing I did could also be done in SQL. But you made me curious, I will install some SQL engine and try it. :)

Comment: Wow! It worked! One minor quirk though: I need the missing values (NULL) to have group_id NULL, not 0. How can I achieve this? Thx!

Comment: And also, how can I add this as a new column to the table? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you want to add it to the table as a permanent, persisted (physically stored on disk) column, you have additional problems dealing with the situation when a new as yet unknown name is added to the data. Tf this is needed, your best bet is to use another table that has (int groupId, varchar GroupName) as the only two columns, join to it from the main table, and have a trigger add a new row whenever a new name is added to the base table.

Comment: Second, there are no "missing" values. The lowest value (0) is assigned to the name that would be first in the alphabet. If name is `null` in some rows of original table, then use third sql I added above.  Finally, if this is solving your problem, please mark it as accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One method is -- as you suggest -- `group by` and `join`.  If the numbers do not have to be sequential:

```
select t.*, minid as group_id
from t join
     (select name, min(id) as minid
      from t
      group by name
     ) tt
     on not t.name <=> tt.name;  -- to handle `NULL`
```

If they do, use variables:

```
select t.*, minid as group_id
from t join
     (select name, min(id) as minid, (@grp := @grp + 1) as group_id
      from t cross join
           (select @grp := -1) params
      group by name
     ) tt
     on not t.name <=> tt.name;  -- to handle `NULL`;
```

You could also do the whole operation with two sorts and variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(not @n <=> name, @grp,
                         if(@n := name, 1, 1)
                        )
             ) as group_id
      from t
           (select @grp := -1, @n := '') params
      order by name
     ) t
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you fot the suggestions. The numbers do not have to be sequential. Which of the three is the fastest? My table has about 200K rows.

Comment: @Amenhotep . . . I would start with the first, although the last might be the fastest if you have an index on `(name)`.